# Write to error stream in while loop

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I’ve got approximately the following code:

```
cat infile | while read line; do
    echo 2> 'log ' $line
    echo $line
done > outfile
```

`outfile` is created correctly. However, the STDERR output just vanished: it’s neither displayed on the terminal nor in `outfile`. If I replace the last line above with `done > outfile 2> errfile` then `errfile` is created, but empty.

Can I capture the error output from within the loop, preferably by streaming it directly into the parent STDERR (the above is part of a larger script whose standard error stream is captured by yet another process)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong: it should be `>&2` not `2>`.

Comment: Duh. Of course.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't work because inside the loop you are redirecting stderr with `2>`. And then when you try to redirect it *again* outside the loop there is nothing left in the stream to redirect.

It would seem that this is what you actually wanted to do:

```
cat infile | while read line; do
    echo >&2 'log ' $line
    echo $line
done > outfile 2> errfile
```

This should redirect all errors from inside the while loop as expected. Unless you have already redirected errors inside the loop, as the example in your question.